# Remove a href from code line

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have a wordpress theme and I'm trying to edit it a little bit. In this topic I want to remove a `href` link from my html which contains image. BTF, I'm noob in coding but theme support doesn't answered so. It is generated with php and js as I understand.

**This is html**

```
 <a href="" class="thumb full_image" ind="0"><img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/DSC06676print-21x15.-900x1323.jpg" class="attachment-gallery-scroll" ind="0"></a>
```

THIS is **code lines which is generating this html** I think soo..

```
$html = sprintf( '<li class="fade" data-url-id="%s"><a %s href="%s" class="%s full_image" title="%s">%s</a></li>',$attachment_id, $rel, $image_link, $image_class, $image_caption, $image );

echo apply_filters( 'easy_image_gallery_html', $html, $rel, $image_link, $image_class, $image_caption, $image, $attachment_id, $post->ID );
```

At the end, I want to have img line like `<img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/DSC06676print-21x15.-900x1323.jpg" class="attachment-gallery-scroll" ind="0">` this without a href, or to have img line first and a href second.

Any ideas? Is it possible? Will be happy for every answer which will get me more closer to the solution. THANKS!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you have now:

```
$html = sprintf( '<li class="fade" data-url-id="%s">
<a %s href="%s" class="%s full_image" title="%s">%s</a></li>',
$attachment_id, $rel, $image_link, $image_class, $image_caption, $image );
```

This is what you need, based on what you've described:

```
$html = sprintf( '<li class="fade" data-url-id="%s">%s</li>',
$attachment_id, $image);
```

**[EDIT]** After the `sprintf` being called for `$html`, there's an `echo` of `apply_filters` function that I don't know the exact role as it's hidden in the rest of your code you didn't show. It's worth consider what it outputs before doing major changes!

Comment: Yes it this code working on 100%, but now slider don't work at all, will open the next topic. (( THANK YOU!

Comment: @user3930317 any time!